# Netbios Names with 2K8

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, netbios

I'm setting up a small network that contains all 2008 servers. No domain controllers, and no DNS (as of yet). Most of the servers will be IIS servers and part of a web farm/pool. Now I have configured the host names to be me more then 15 characters long. eg. NAME-LOCATION-PROD-WEB1. Now I know that NETbios is soon to be a thing of the past and none of our applications require netbios name resolution. Should I set up a DNS server with a primary/secondary zone to contain the hostnames? Should I be concerned about the Duplicate name warning if no Netbios resolution will be taking place? Should I take a look at global name zones? What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't require it and it isn't causing any problems, then there's nothing to worry about. If these boxes don't need to communicate via hostname you don't really need DNS, though it should help with management in general.

Comment: I would actualy like to connect with host names DNS servers are probably going to be a must. Beats adding entries manually to each host file on each server. What do you think?

Comment: Absolutely use DNS.

Comment: Absolutely use public DNS

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen what good will public DNS do? If he needs these machines to resolve each others names, local DNS seems like a more reasonable bet.

Comment: @MDMarra hadn't thought that comment through, my apologies